# Different shell for tty and SSH sessions for a single user

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, prompt, tty

I use the zsh on a daily basis, and I really like its fancy prompts one can choose. And I am managing a simple Linux server, usually through ssh.

However, I sometimes need to be there locally to manually configure some stuff (things like initial installation, firewall configuration, etc), rather than through ssh. And in those cases I have to use the tty, as we have no GUI enabled (runlevel 3). The TTY does not seem to like powerline fonts, colors, and such. So I would be happy if I could just login directly to bash rather than zsh in those cases, but I am not sure how to implement it without wreaking havoc. Maybe a conditional in a file such as .profile? Or should it be somewhere else?

Needless to say, this should happen at the user level (the rest of the users are fine with bash anyway).

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see how _powerlike fonts_ (whatever this means) is related to the shell. The shell is not aware of the idea of a "font". Also, regardless of what "colour support" the shell offer - if you can see different colours at all is not something the shell can influence, but depends on your terminal capabilities.

Comment: I'm afraid I meant "powerline" instead of "powerlike", it was a typo. In any case, I am not saying the shell knows about it. I say that ttys display them as they can. The thing is that in zsh the prompt configured is fancy, in bash it is plain text (with maybe some colors), that is why I wanted to default to bash in ttys. Perhaps this clarifies it.

Comment: It does, but I then suggest to put this information into the question itself, instead of a comment.

Comment: In this case, you could in your .zshrc use `tput` to query your terminal capabilities, and depending on what the terminal can do, configure your prompt differently.